# SonarQube / TeamCity - Code Coverage Empty

Tags: .net, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan

TeamCity Professional 10.0 (build 42002)
SonarQube Version 6.0

Simple Visual Studio solution, two projects:

- MVC Website
- Parallel project for unit tests

Three build steps:

- Install NuGet packages
- Build Solution (MS Build 14.0)
- SonarQube Analysis

All three steps appear to run without incident.  SonarQube does not show any code coverage.  Treemap entirely gray - lines of code shows, but no coverage percentage.  I am unable to discern whether coverage is not being calculated, or if it is just not being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

The computation of code coverage and the import of code coverage reports is not magical. It's your responsibility to use a code coverage tool to generate a coverage report and then to configure the SonarQube analysis to import this report. See http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/CoBh